# Deoplete Dictionary Completition

Tags: vim, autocomplete, spell-checking

I am new to VIM/NEOVIM and I want to create a basic command in my .vimrc which lets my deoplete autocomplete use English and German dictionaries. I have the following already in my .vimrc:

```
set dictionary=/usr/share/myspell/de_AT.dic
set dictionary+=/usr/share/myspell/en_US.dic
call deoplete#custom#source('dictionary', 'matchers', ['matcher_head'])
call deoplete#custom#source('dictionary', 'sorters', [])
call deoplete#custom#source('dictionary', 'min_pattern_length', 4)
```

but this doesn't work, I get no word proposals from deoplete. What additionally would be nice if I could swap the autocompletition on the fly like I do with the spell checker (see below). Is this possible?

```
set nospell
map <silent> <leader>de :setlocal spell spelllang=de_at spelllang? <CR>
map <silent> <leader>en :setlocal spell spelllang=en_us spelllang? <CR>
map <silent> <leader>ns :setlocal nospell spelllang= spell? <CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution if someone is interested

```
set complete+=kspell
set nospell
map <silent> <leader>de :setlocal spell spelllang=de spelllang? <CR>
map <silent> <leader>en :setlocal spell spelllang=en spelllang? <CR>
map <silent> <leader>ns :setlocal nospell spelllang= spell? <CR>
inoremap <silent> <C-s> <C-x><C-k>
```

This doesn't use deoplete, but instead the build in omnicomplete. Pressing CTRL+s will pop up a list of dictionary words based on the seplllang dictionary.